# Prove that $|f(x)|\le |x|+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(0) = 1$ and $|f'(x)|\le1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, prove that $|f(x)|\le|x|+1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is differentiable on  $\mathbb R$ which means it's also continuous, thus we can apply the *Mean Value Theorem* on a domain $(0,x)$ :

$$f'(ξ) = \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0}$$

By taking absolute values, we'd get :

$$|f'(ξ)| = \Bigg| \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} \Bigg| \Leftrightarrow |f'(ξ)||x|=|f(x) -1|$$

But $|f'(x)| \leq 1$, thus :

$$|f(x)-1|\leq|x| \Rightarrow |f(x)| \leq |x| + 1$$

Answer (score 8):

Mean value Theorem: $|f(x)-f(0)|=|f'(\xi_{x})||x|\leq|x|$, then...

Comment: That's really a clever kill there!